# Is there a way to fill an array with user input one at a time instead of looping through the whole array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm working on my final assignment for my C# course and making a type of "bus simulator" for lack of a better description, it's working with a case switch menu and one of the functions is for the user to add a passenger and determine their age which then gets added to an array that has room for 25 numbers.

I've worked with arrays and user input before but only ever with the program looping until the whole of the array is filled, what I would like to do though it make it so that the program asks the passengers age, saves it, goes back to the menu and then if the option is picked again it will do the same with the next empty spot in the array. Is this something that's possible to do? here's my code, it's far from done but the first menu option is throwing me off.

```
class Buss
    {
        public int [] passenger = new int[25];

        public void Run()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome onboard on todays fabulous bus tour!");

            int temp = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("what would you like to do?");
                Console.WriteLine("1 add a passenger");
                Console.WriteLine("2 print list of passengers");
                Console.WriteLine("3 calculate total age of passengers");
                Console.WriteLine("0 end program");
                temp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (temp)
                { 
                       case 1: add_passenger();
                       break;
                       case 2: print_buss();
                       break;
                       case 3: calc_total_age();
                       break;
                       case 0: Console.WriteLine("the program is turning off, goodbye!");
                       break;
                       default: Console.WriteLine("wrong input");
                       break;
                }


            }while (temp != 0);
        }


        public void add_passenger() //adds passengers to the bus, to do: add for option not to work if the bus is full
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < passenger.Length; i++)
            {   
                Console.WriteLine("how old is the passenger?");
                passenger[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
            }
        }

        public void print_buss() //print ages of everyone on the bus
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the passangers on the buss are:");

            foreach (int x in passenger) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x); 
            }
        }

        public void calc_total_age() //calculate the complete ages of everyone on the bus, to do: change "void" to "int"
        {

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var minbuss = new Buss();
            minbuss.Run();
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should handle invalid input with `int.TryParse`

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard You cannot simply add items to an array.

Comment: @DavidG yes, actually, you can. Look at the code OP posted again. Specifically the array declaration. He initializes it to size 25. You know, that's how he's doing `passenger[i]=value` in his code, right?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

**Option 1: new array each time.**

Initially, you create an empty array:

```
public int [] passenger = new int[0];
```

When adding a passenger, you just create a new array that has one more element than previous one. Don't forget to copy the contents of the old array to the new one:

```
public void add_passenger()
{
    if (passenger.Length >= 25)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the bus is full");                
        return;
    }

    var oldPassengers = passenger;
    passenger = new int[passenger.Length + 1];
    Array.Copy(oldPassengers, passenger, olsPassengers.Length);

    Console.WriteLine("how old is the passenger?");
    passenger[passenger.Length - 1] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
}
```

**Option 2: use nullable `int`s.**

`null` means a seat is free, a non-null value is the passenger age.

```
public int? [] passenger = new int?[25];

public void add_passenger()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < passenger.Length; i++)
    {   
        if (passenger[i] is null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("how old is the passenger?");
            passenger[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
            return;
        }                
    }

    // if we reach here, then we checked all the array and didn't find a free seat (null)
    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the bus is full");                
}
```

**Option 3: store index of last free seat.**

Introduce a new variable that will hold the index of the next free seat. If it equals the array size, that means there are no free seats anymore.

```
public int [] passenger = new int[25];
int freeSeat = 0;

public void add_passenger()
{
    if (freeSeat >= passenger.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, the bus is full");                
        return;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("how old is the passenger?");
    passenger[freeSeat] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
    freeSeat++;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store count of passenger in an int property.
So your class will have `int passengerCount = 0;`
Then, each time when adding passenger you should just modify count.

So it will be:

```
public void AddPassenger()
{
      if(passengerCount > passenger.Length - 1)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Bus is full");
          return;
      }

      Console.WriteLine("how old is the passenger?");
      passenger[passengerCount] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
      passengerCount ++;
}
```

Comment: `passengerCount >= passenger.Length` is clearer in most instances.

Answer (score -1):

There are some problems with using `int[25]` to contain a maximum of 25 ints.

- What if you allow for 25 values but only get 23? It's unnecessarily difficult to tell how many items have been populated. You'd have to keep track with a separate variable.
- It would be very easy to make a mistake and populate the wrong element in the array - for example, populating index 1 first instead of 0, or populating them out of order.

A `List<int>` is likely a better option.

```
public List<int> passengers = new List<int>();
```

Now to add a value:

```
passengers.Add(value);
```

To find out how many are in the collection:

```
passengers.Count;
```

As requirements change it's also easier to take a passenger off the bus:

```
passengers.RemoveAt(12);
```

You could use a variable to determine how many users are allowed on the bus:

```
var maximumPassengers = 25;
```

Now, after adding a passenger, you could check

```
if(passengers.Count >= maximumPassengers)
```

...and use that to control the flow and stop accepting new passengers.

If, for some odd reason, your instructor says that you must use an array, just tell them that the inner implementation of `List<T>` *is* an array. It's creating an array, keeping track of the last index populated, and setting values within the array. If it needs to it copies the items to a bigger array. In other words, it's doing all of that work for you so that you don't have to write extra code for it.

Comment: That last sentence is... actually a really good point... I would love to hear the instructors reaction to that!

Comment: @DavidG That was speculation on my part, though. Nothing in the question says it has to be an array.

Comment: @ScottHannen The comments (that have not very annoyingly been deleted) did say an array was required though.

Comment: @DavidG In that case I'll leave it. I can only provide an answer to the question as asked, not to deleted comments.

Comment: @ScottHannen Indeed, which is why it's annoying they were deleted. But my comment was directed at Broots rather than you. Using a `List<>` here is absolutely the right thing to do.

Comment: @DavidG - I'm glad someone likes it! :)